# where is the mistake in my for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

`Targets` contains the target values and `Observation` contains the observations.
     I want my for-loop to count the number of different target values for each of the observation values and store them in the matrix `obs_array` where rows are the object values and the columns are the the target values. 
for the examples that I have provided it must return:

```
obs_array = [[3,2],[2 5]]
```

meaning that for zeros in the observation, there are 3 times 0 in the target values and 2 times 1 (the first list) and for the ones in the observations there are 2 times 0 and 5 times 1 (the second list)
but the loop is not working correctly. Can you find the problem and explain it for me? (I am new to Python)

```
Target = [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
Observation = [1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]

target_values = list(set(S))
observation_values = list(set(A))
obs_array = [[0 for x in range(len(observation_values))] for x in range(len(target_values))]

for k in range(len(observation_values)):
    for kk in range(len(Observation)):
        if observation_values[k] == Observation[kk]:
           for kkk in range(len(Target)):
               for kkkk in range(len(target_values)):
                   if Target[kkk] == target_values[kkkk]:
                       obs_array[k][kkkk]+=1

print(obs_array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's not really an answer to your question, but here's a fun solution to your problem (partly to help others understand what you're asking for, because the question is quite confusing):

```
from collections import Counter

for (s, a), count in Counter(zip(S, A)).items():
    obs_array[s][a] = count

print obs_array  # [[3, 2], [2, 5]]
```

EDIT: I realise now that there's no need for such tricks. This code will also work:

```
for i in range(len(S)):
    obs_array[S[i]][A[i]] += 1
```

Comment: Your problem isn't very clear. Does `Counter(zip(S, A))` solve it?

Comment: thanks.  but can show me how to do it when there are more values in A (Observations)?

Comment: You need to make your problem clearer. Add another example with more values in A.